# Received a python syntax error while running the below code

Tags: python

Errors is thrown to verify if the character in a string is empty:

Python code

```
def first_and_last(message):
  if(message[0] ==  message[-1] or len(message[0])==0):
     return True
   return False
print(first_and_last("else"))
print(first_and_last("tree"))
print(first_and_last(""))
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                            
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>                                                                                         
    print(first_and_last(""))                                                                                                 
  File "main.py", line 2, in first_and_last                                                                                   
    if(message[0] ==  message[-1] or len(message[0])==0):                                                                     
IndexError: **string index out of range**
```

Comment: That's not a syntax error, it's a runtime error.

Comment: What do you think happens with `message[0]` and `message[-1]` if the string is empty?

Comment: Hint: empty lists do not have the first item.

Comment: Based on your function name and invocation, you probably meant to check `len(message)` (and you will need to order it correctly).

Comment: index out of range means that the index you are trying to access does not exist. In a string, that means you're trying to get a character from the string at a given point that doesn't exists.

Comment: @user65314 Actually what you are trying to achieve. what is the purpose of `first_and_last` function. Do you want to check whether the last character in a string is equal or  not?

Comment: Put `if message and (message[0] == message[-1] or len(message[0]) == 0):` if message has no members in its list, then the first test will fail and the rest of the expression won't be evaluated - thus avoiding the `IndexError`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare for an empty string before you access its elements. Your condition should be:

```
if(len(message)==0 or message[0] ==  message[-1]):
```

And it should be `len(message)` and not `len(message[0])` because if your `message` is empty, there would not be any `message[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to make sure that the message is not empty string.
use this method, it returns 0 which evaluates false, and true when first and last chars are same.

```
def first_and_last(message):
  return len(message) and message[0] == message[-1]
```

Comment: I prefer `len(message) != 0 and message[0] == message[-1]` not to mix integers and booleans.
This do not throw errors for `and` is lazy in python tests [see doc](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
def first_and_last(message):
  if(len(message)==0):
     return True
  elif(message[0] ==  message[-1] or len(message[0])==0):
     return True  
  return False
print(first_and_last("else"))
print(first_and_last("tree"))
print(first_and_last(""))
```

The error was you have to mention the case of checking empty string as well since you were passing the empty string in the function.